# tree data structure (level_order)

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

I'm learning tree data structure about `preorder`, `postorder`, `inorder` and `level_order`. These code are written by C. When i assign the `temp -> item` to element item in dequeue method, make the error. But i think `struct` pointer can save another `struct` pointer! how can i solve it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct QueueNode {
    int item;
    struct QueueNode *link; 
} QueueNode;
typedef struct {
    QueueNode *front, *rear;
} QueueType;

typedef struct TreeNode {
    int data;
    struct TreeNode *left, *right;
} TreeNode;

typedef TreeNode * element;


void error(char *message)
{
fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",message);
exit(1);
}


void init(QueueType *q)
{
    q->front = q->rear = 0;
}

int is_empty(QueueType *q)
{
    return (q->front==NULL);
}

int is_full(QueueType *q)
{
    return 0;
}

void enqueue(QueueType *q, element item)
{ 
    QueueNode *temp=(QueueNode *)malloc(sizeof(QueueNode)); 
    if(temp == NULL )
        error("error");
    else {
        temp->item = item;
        temp->link = NULL;
        if( is_empty(q) ){
            q->front = temp;
            q->rear = temp;     
        }
        else {
            q->rear->link = temp;
            q->rear = temp; 
        }   
    }
}

element dequeue(QueueType *q) 
{ 
    QueueNode *temp = q -> front;
    element item; 
    if( is_empty(q) )
        error("error");
    else {
        item = temp->item;
        q->front = q->front->link;
        if( q->front == NULL )
        q->rear = NULL;
        free(temp);
        return item;
    }
} 


void level_order(TreeNode *ptr)
{
    QueueType q;

    init(&q);
    if( !ptr ) return;
    enqueue(&q, ptr);
    while(is_empty(&q)) {
        ptr = dequeue(&q);
        printf(" %d ", ptr->data);
        if( ptr->left )
            enqueue(&q, ptr->left);
        if( ptr->right )
            enqueue(&q, ptr->right);
    }
}

TreeNode n1={1,  NULL, NULL};
TreeNode n2={2,  &n1,  NULL};
TreeNode n3={4, NULL,  NULL};
TreeNode n4={8, NULL, NULL};
TreeNode n5={10, NULL, NULL};
TreeNode n6={6, NULL, NULL};
TreeNode n7={9, &n4,  &n5};
TreeNode n8={7, &n6, &n7};
TreeNode n9={3, &n2,  &n3};
TreeNode n10={5, &n9,  &n8};
TreeNode *root= &n10;



void main()
{
    level_order(root);

}
```

Comment: `enqueue` and `dequeue` are apparently operations on queues. using these names for trees is a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function `dequeue`, this assignment -

```
item = temp->item;
```

`item` is a pointer to structure `TreeNode` , but `temp->item` is a integer variable. Compiler obviously will give an error (*didn't excatly know what were you trying to accomplish*).

Comment: `didn't know what were you trying` +1 for that :))

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign member of a structure `temp->item` to a structure `item` in **dequeue** and structure `item` to a member of a structure `temp->item` in **enqueue**.

**Dequeue:** Here you are returning type **int**, change return type **element** to **int** (`item = temp->item;` This statement is incorrect). So this is correct way of dequeue.

```
int  dequeue(QueueType *q) 
{ 
    QueueNode *temp = q -> front;
    element item; 
    if( is_empty(q) )
        error("error");
    else {
        item->data = temp->item;
        q->front = q->front->link;
        if( q->front == NULL )
        q->rear = NULL;
        free(temp);
        return item;
    }
}
```

**Enqueue:** Use this function for enqueue(`temp->item = item;` this statement is incorrect):

```
void enqueue(QueueType *q, element item)
{ 
    QueueNode *temp=(QueueNode *)malloc(sizeof(QueueNode)); 
    if(temp == NULL )
        error("error");
    else {
        temp->item = item->data;
        temp->link = NULL;
        if( is_empty(q) ){
            q->front = temp;
            q->rear = temp;     
        }
        else {
            q->rear->link = temp;
            q->rear = temp; 
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of dequeue:

```
int dequeue(QueueType *q)
{
    QueueNode *temp = q -> front;
    int item;
    if( is_empty(q) )
        error("error");
    else {
        item = temp->item;
        q->front = q->front->link;
        if( q->front == NULL )
            q->rear = NULL;
        free(temp);
        return item;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The type of data you supposed to return is `int`.